# LIBOR OIS equation - Discount factor

Tags: fx

I've seen this equation floating around :

XCCY = FX OIS + USD LIBOR/OIS - EUR LIBOR/OIS.

This equation is intuitive however there's a mention that discount factors between the two need to be taken into account. What does this mean and how does this apply in the equation?